# JW Player Error#2124 for youtube videos

Tags: asp.net, youtube, jwplayer

I am an ASP.Net developer, i am using JW Player in my site to use videos directly from youtube.
Its working perfectly. But there is an issue, that when once i disconnect youtube (internet),
 it don't play video`(gives error#2124 as it should give).`But again when i connect youtube 
(internet) and play videos, it again(still) shows the same `error#2124` until and unless i don't clear
browser's cache.When i clear the cache of browser it normally play the videos. I don't want to clear cache of browser 
menually or programmatically because cache always
contains some other important things too. So please is there any other way, so that when i 
re-connect internet, it should normally play rather than to show same error#2124. 
Here is my player setup:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                        file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + myonlyyoutubefilename,
                        height: 380,
                        width: 750,
                        autostart: 'true',

                    });
```

//Here 'myElement' is the id of my player's div.

Comment: Can you provide a link?